# Getting error when i installing angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When i installing angular cli i am getting following error

my command: `$ npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`
error:

```
C:\Users\rans\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> 
C:\Users\rans\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

> @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall 
C:\Users\rans\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/ng-update-message.js

 npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
 npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
 fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
 {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

 + @angular/cli@6.0.8
 updated 1 package in 19.492s
```

How to clear this error?

I installed following version:

npm version 6.1.0

node version 6.9.5

Comment: This is not an error. It's a warning. The angular CLI should work fine for You.

Comment: not working...getting this error:$ ng new test
bash: ng: command not found

Comment: try ```npm uninstall -g @angular/cli ,
npm cache clean ,
npm cache verify ,
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest``` then tell the result.

Comment: thats not an error, if you read the description its clear what it is

Comment: fateme fazli : same.i am getting same issue

Comment: Help me anyone..How to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

It might be of your node version. Try update node to 8.

Comment: I do not have admin permision.So how can i update it?